# Eclipse and JSP typing speed

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have read here about eclipse standard JSP validation plugin having performance issues, but I could not find a working solution. I've unticked all relevant options for my project and even restarted the IDE to see if that works, but I'm still typing with 1 character per second.

Am I the only one who still experiences the problem after disabling JSP validation?
Alternatively can you recommend me a different eclipse editor/plugin that does the job better?

[image]

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Which editor in Eclipse are you using (check the file's Open With context menu)? Is the file on a local disk?

Comment: Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: That's one of three things answered.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't know how I missed the other two.
In 'open with' the JSP Editor is marked as the one in use.
And the file is stored on a network drive.

Comment: Try putting it, and the project it is in, on a local drive. Lots of things might need to read files in the background for purposes other than to provide validation feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unselect validators from Builders tab of your project's properties.

[image]

Comment: won't that disable all of them?

Comment: Once upon a time I faced the same problem. As I remember, this change solved it. But, I do not remember which validator is the correct one.